# Access 2007 VBA code returns only the first record of the loop

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access-2007

I have two tables, I am trying to get data from table B into table A. If The ID for table A is not found in table B then leave it null. 
Eg.

```
             AID    Sttl                    BID      Sttl
             4                              88        3
             20                             92        2
             88     3                       100       8 
             92     2                       500       10
             800
```

The code I currently have only return the first similar record in table A. It does not return the next matching record (eg. it returns 3 for AID 88 but does not return anything for AID92). What am i missing?

```
 Dim db As dao.Database
 Dim rs1 As dao.Recordset
 Dim rs2 As dao.Recordset

 Set db = CurrentDb()
 Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset(cstrFromtbl, dbOpenDynaset)
 Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset(cstrTotbl, dbOpenDynaset)

Do While Not rs2.EOF
If rs2.Fields("A.ID") = rs1.Fields("B.ID") Then
   rs2.Edit
   rs2.Fields("Sttl") = rs1.Fields("Sttl")
   rs2.Update
Else
   rs2.Edit
   rs2.Fields("Sttl") = Null
   rs2.Update
End If
rs2.MoveNext
Loop

Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: first of all you need to make sure that you ordered the tables by id. And I don't see in your code something like rs1.MoveNext. Is this code right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong but it looks like you are recreating SQL in VBA.  The SQL below is simpler and will probably run much, much faster.

```
UPDATE tablea
INNER JOIN tableb
ON tablea.idfield = tableb.idfield
SET tablea.destinationfield = tableb.sourcefield
```

Comment: I tried doing this in SQL before attempting VBA. Right now I have `Else rs2.Edit rs2.Fields("Sttl") = Null rs2.Update End If` However, this is in a test environment. I will be adding an expression instead of null. eg. `If ID = 4 then Sttl = 1.5 * field2 ` I dont see a ay to do this in SQL

Comment: I think you can address this additional requirement by using a second Update statement. You can use a lookup table to decide what to do when the ID field is a certain value or within a range of values. If you don't want to use a lookup table in Access you can use nested `IF` statements to determine how to do an update, or in SQL Server you can use a `CASE` statement to enumerate all the different scenarios.

Comment: I need 3 update statement to get the job done. Thanks for all the suggests. Its running prefectly now.

Answer (score 1):

What many forgot, you can't be sure about the order of a table except you sort it. Therfore you have to do a search, and check if something was found.

```
Do While Not rs2.EOF
  rs1.FindFirst("ID=" & rs2.Fields("A.ID"))
  rs2.Edit
  If rs1.NoMatch Then
   rs2.Fields("Sttl") = Null
  Else
   rs2.Fields("Sttl") = rs1.Fields("Sttl")
  EndIF
  rs2.Update
  rs2.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks Jorg, this didnt work for me in this case but I was able to use the code on another table.